# Awk consider double quoted string as one token and ignore space in between

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Data file - data.txt:

```
ABC "I am ABC" 35 DESC
DEF "I am not ABC" 42 DESC
```

`cat data.txt | awk '{print $2}'`

will result the "I" instead of the string being quoted

How to make awk so that it ignore the space within the quote and think that it is one single token?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this can be done nicely in awk. It's easy to get all the fields without any serious hacks.

(This example works in both [The One True Awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Versions_and_implementations) and in gawk.)

```
{
  split($0, a, "\"")
  $2 = a[2]
  $3 = $(NF - 1)
  $4 = $NF
  print "and the fields are ", $1, "+", $2, "+", $3, "+", $4
}
```

Comment: To format for a one liner: `cat data.txt | awk 'split($0, a, "\"") {$2 = a[2]} {$3 = $(NF - 1)} {$4 = $NF} {print "and the fields are ", $1, "+", $2, "+", $3, "+", $4}'`

Comment: This only works if you have a single quoted field, on the second position, and have 4 fields in total. It's not generic. A solution where it will accept any quoted field in any position will be ideal.

Answer (score 26):

Another alternative would be to use the [`FPAT`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html) variable, that defines a regular expression describing the contents of each field.

Save this AWK script as `parse.awk`:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
}
{
  print $2
}
```

Make it executable with `chmod +x ./parse.awk` and parse your data file as `./parse.awk data.txt`:

```
"I am ABC"
"I am not ABC"
```

Comment: Thank you for the regex! ;-) Saved me at least 20 minutes of frustrated attempts. +1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: this is the best answer, So I can use following command to convert my logs to prevent using FPAT every time:  echo 'filed1 "the second field"' | awk 'BEGIN {FPAT = "([^ ]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(" ","%20",$i)} print}'

Comment: This works with GNU awk, but not the awk that ships with Mac OS X, so do `brew install gawk` if you're on a Mac.

Comment: Wow, using `FPAT` is elegant! Although that regex fails at strings like `ABC="I am ABC" 35 DESC`, it could be easily adjusted for them: `FPAT = "([^ ]+)?(\"[^\"]+\")?"`. Unsure if it's the most effective way.

Comment: PS. It still didn't work for more complex strings like `"go ABC"="I am ABC" 35 DESC` and `ABC="I am ABC"=Yeee 35 DESC`. So I made it more robust: `FPAT = "(([^ ]+)?(\"[^\"]+\")?)+"` (even if uglier).

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$ cat data.txt | awk -F\" '{print $2}'
I am ABC
I am not ABC
```

Comment: I should note that this isn't particularly generic -- it simply changes the field separator to `" and selects the second field.

Comment: But if I want to use the information before and after... it won't work =(

Comment: @Roy Chan -- true.  Awk is not really the right tool for parsing quoted strings.  Go down to the third post [at this horribly formatted Google Cache link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:HA9Ix2yPEasJ:forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do%3FthreadId%3D1028610+awk+quotes+field&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=safari&source=www.google.com) and you can see an example that is much longer but might help.

Comment: @DigitalRoss -- nice solution; I hadn't thought of that method.

Comment: @RoyChan This solution is usable by doubling the index (but only if every field has quotes). You can use a higher number, and it will work. Just add more to the index than you think, to account for the blank when there are two quotes in a row, since the quote is used as the field delimiter which generates more fields. For example, to use something after, do: `echo "'hello there' 'the world'" | awk -F\' '{print $4}'` (The result is "the world" without quotes). But if some have no quote: `echo "'hello there' the world" | awk -F\' '{print $3}'` yields " the world" without quotes but with a space.

Answer (score 5):

The top answer for this question only works for lines with a single quoted field. When I found this question I needed something that could work for an arbitrary number of quoted fields.

Eventually I came upon [an answer by Wintermute in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28063726/3756197), and he provided a good generalized solution to this problem. I've just modified it to remove the quotes. Note that you need to invoke awk with `-F\"` when running the below program.

```
BEGIN { OFS = "" } {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 2) {
        gsub(/[ \t]+/, ",", $i)
    }
    print
}
```

This works by observing that every other element in the array will be inside of the quotes when you separate by the "-character, and so it replaces the whitespace dividing the ones not in quotes with a comma.

You can then easily chain another instance of awk to do whatever processing you need (just use the field separator switch again, `-F,`).

Note that this might break if the first field is quoted - I haven't tested it. If it does, though, it should be easy to fix by adding an if statement to start at 2 rather than 1 if the first character of the line is a ".

Answer (score 3):

I've scrunched up together a function that re-splits $0 into an array called B. Spaces between double quotes are not acting as field separators. Works with any number of fields, a mix of quoted and unquoted ones. Here goes:

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

# Resplit $0 into array B. Spaces between double quotes are not separators.
# Single quotes not handled. No escaping of double quotes.
function resplit(       a, l, i, j, b, k, BNF) # all are local variables
{
  l=split($0, a, "\"")
  BNF=0
  delete B
  for (i=1;i<=l;++i)
  {
    if (i % 2)
    {
      k=split(a[i], b)
      for (j=1;j<=k;++j)
        B[++BNF] = b[j]
    }
    else
    {
      B[++BNF] = "\""a[i]"\""
    }
  }
}

{
  resplit()

  for (i=1;i<=length(B);++i)
    print i ": " B[i]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. But it doesn't work for lines like `ABC="I am ABC" 35 DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something like what I finally got working that is more generic for my project.
Note it doesn't use awk.

```
someText="ABC \"I am ABC\" 35 DESC '1 23' testing 456"
putItemsInLines() {
    local items=""
    local firstItem="true"
    while test $# -gt 0; do
        if [ "$firstItem" == "true" ]; then
            items="$1"
            firstItem="false"
        else
            items="$items
$1"
        fi
        shift
    done
    echo "$items"
}

count=0
while read -r valueLine; do
    echo "$count: $valueLine"
    count=$(( $count + 1 ))
done <<< "$(eval putItemsInLines $someText)"
```

Which outputs:

```
0: ABC
1: I am ABC
2: 35
3: DESC
4: 1 23
5: testing
6: 456
```

Comment: Upvoted for using pure shell! Doesn't work in Bourne shells though. But two slight changes fix that (Lines 8 and 24:)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you really want all three fields, you can get them, but it takes a lot of piping:

```
$ cat data.txt | awk -F\" '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3}' | awk -F' ,' '{print $1 "," $2}' | awk -F', ' '{print $1 "," $2}' | awk -F, '{print $1 "," $2 "," $3}'
ABC,I am ABC,35
DEF,I am not ABC,42
```

By the last pipe you've got all three fields to do whatever you'd like with.

Comment: Actually, there are 4 fields.

Comment: Oops -- I missed that in the original submission.