# How to remove double quotes in a specific column by using sub() in AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My sample data is

```
cat > myfile
"a12","b112122","c12,d12"
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

when I try to remove **"** from colum 2 by

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /"/ { sub(/"/, "", $2) }1' myfile 
"a12",b112122","c12,d12"
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

It only remove only 1 comma, instead of **b112122** i am getting **b112122"**

**how to remove all " in 2nd column**

Comment: Why about your last question? You haven't  accepted it but yet moved on to a different one

Comment: Please give me sometime... Just sorting out full question. I notice once I click on vote, dosnt matter if I ask further there for same issue no one reply. so didnt vote yet

Comment: @WDC, Your thread title says `,` comma but letter which you are trying to remove is NOT `,`(comma) it is double quote`"` just letting you know here.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 

Its not "How to remove all double quotes by using sub() function of awk in a specific field" its . "How to remove double quotes in a specific column by using sub() function of awk in a specific field"

Comment: @WDC, Sure, please feel free to edit your question, cheers.

Comment: @WDC, I completely understood meaning of question + I given answer also(which I deleted later). I was trying to fix to make it more clear simple.

Comment: Since you edit the title to not specify what column to change, you should look at what will work for all column.  The solution you have accepted fails if there are `,` within second column.

Comment: But the answer you got will fail in many situation and should not be accepted.  Also calling people name here is not needed.  We are here to help, and Ravider has been here for years helping out.   Mary Xmas....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html):

> Search target, which is treated as a string, for the leftmost, longest substring matched by the regular expression regexp.[...] Return the number of substitutions made (zero or one).

It is quite clear that the function `sub` is doing at most one single replacement and does not replace all occurences.

Instead, use `gsub`:

> Search target for all of the longest, leftmost, nonoverlapping matching substrings it can find and replace them with replacement. The ‘g’ in gsub() stands for “global,” which means replace everywhere.

So you can add a 'g' to your line and it works fine:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } $2 ~ /"/ { gsub(/"/, "", $2) }1' myfile
```

Comment: Try to change to column number 3 and this solution fails.

Comment: @Jotne Could you please explain what is failing? It removes the beginning quote mark. If you are referring to the fact that columns 3 and 4 should not be split, it's another matter. I would use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43213844/1507014) in this case.

Comment: @Jotne I am doing testing in 196 different files, 1st 2 files work for me till now... all 196 files have different structure ... 

1st i need to remove comma then double quote and need to remove + . and space in 19th column .. and so on... so far-reaching goal... but I guess if 2-3 people say its not good answer.. please wait so I can update .. i cant be quick.. i am not a pro yet

Comment: @wdc It works on the second file and gives the result like this `"a12",b112122,"c12,d12"` but if you try column #3, you get `"a12","b112122",c12,d12"`, it should be `"a12","b112122",c12,d12`  but then you should also change the field separator to some else than `,`.  Se my second example.

Answer (score 0):

When you dealing with CSV file, not using `FPAT`, it will break sooner or later.
Here is a `gnu awk` that does the jib.

```
awk -v OFS="," -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{gsub(/"/,"",$2)}1' file
"a12",b112122,"c12,d12"
a13,887988,c13,d13
a14,b14121,c79,d13
```

It will work fine on any column, number 3 as well.

Example on remove `"` on column 3 at the same time change separator to `|`

```
awk -v OFS="|" -v FPAT="([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" '{gsub(/"/,"",$3);$1=$1}1' file
"a12"|"b112122"|c12,d12
a13|887988|c13|d13
a14|b14121|c79|d13
```